Error in RStudio when attempting to knit RMarkdown with animations into an HTML

I have been trying to knit my RMarkdown file into an html but keep getting this error. It occurs wherever I have an animation in the code, and I am using gifski_renderer() to render the animations. All the animations work in RStudio itself, it just causes a problem when I am trying to knit.
Edit: Ok, it seems to work if I significantly lower the resolution or the height/width of the animation, but it is still taking an absurdly long time to render anything big enough to use. Not sure if there are any fixes for that but it would be super helpful if anyone knew how to more effectively upload a bigger animation to the html.

It might make sense to render the animations in another file and only embedd the result in the report.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
